# How to pythonically select a random index from a 2D list such that the corresponding element matches a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

I have a 2D list of booleans. I want to select a random index from the the list where the value is `False`. For example, given the following list:

```
[[True, False, False],
 [True, True, True],
 [False, True, True]]
```

The valid choices would be: `[0, 1]`, `[0, 2]`, and `[2, 0]`.

I could keep a list of valid indices and then use `random.choice` to select from it, but it seems unpythonic to keep a variable and update it every time the underlying list changes for only this one purpose.

Bonus points if your answer runs quickly.

Comment: The given output is not valid, you probably look for 2-item lists?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited. I wrote it that way because that is how you would perform a lookup. But yeah it was confusing

Comment: How often are you making these choices, and how often are you modifying the list of lists? It sounds like keeping an auxiliary data structure to track valid indices would save a lot of computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a oneliner like:

```
import numpy as np
from random import choice

choice(np.argwhere(~a))
```

With `a` the array of booleans.

This works as follows: by using `~a`, we *negate* the elements of the array. Next we use `np.argwhere` to construct a *k×2*-array: an array where every row has two elements: for every dimension the value such that the corresponding value has as value `False`.

By `choice(..)` we thus select a random row. We can however not use this directly to access the element. We can use the `tuple(..)` constructor to cast it to a tuple:

```
>>> tuple(choice(np.argwhere(~a)))
(2, 0)
```

You can thus fetch the element then with:

```
t = tuple(choice(np.argwhere(~a)))
a[t]
```

But of course, it is not a surprise that:

```
>>> t = tuple(choice(np.argwhere(~a)))
>>> a[t]
False
```

Comment: This could be simplified using [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

Comment: @user2357112: thanks, did not know about `argwhere`.

Answer (score 3):

My non-numpy version:

```
result = random.choice([
    (i,j)
    for i in range(len(a)) 
    for j in range(len(a[i])) 
    if not a[i][j]])
```

Like Willem's `np` version, this generates a list of valid tuples and invokes `random.choice()` to pick one.

Alternatively, if you hate seeing `range(len(...))` as much as I do, here is an `enumerate()` version:

```
result = random.choice([
    (i, j)
    for i, row in enumerate(a)
    for j, cell in enumerate(row)
    if not cell])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to use numpy.

```
matrix = [[True, False, False],
          [True, True, True],
          [False, True, True]]

valid_choices = [(i,j) for i, x in enumerate(matrix) for j, y in enumerate(x) if not y]
random.choice(valid_choices)
```

With list comprehensions, you can change the if condition (`if not y`) to suit your needs. This will return the coordinate that is randomly selected, but optionally you could change the value part of the list comprehension `(i,j)` in this case to: `y` and it'd return false, though thats a bit redundant in this case.