# Select a random element from a 2d array list in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I currently have a 2d array generated by this code:

```
for y in range(width):
    self.grid.append([])
    for x in range(width):
        self.grid[y].append(Cell(x, y))
```

If I want to select a random cell, how would I go about it? random.choice doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Pick a random `x` value, a random `y`, and your random cell will be `self.grid[random_x][random_y]`. You can use `random.randint` or `random.randrange` to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pythonically select a random index from a 2D list such that the corresponding element matches a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631962/how-to-pythonically-select-a-random-index-from-a-2d-list-such-that-the-correspon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
yCoord = random.randrange(width)
xCoord = random.randrange(width)
randomCell = self.grid[yCoord][xCoord]
```

If you do want to use `random.choice`, you'll have to use it twice, as the first call will return an array of Cells, then the second one will return a cell element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s = list[random.randint(0, len(list) - 1]
rn = s[random.randint(0, len(s) - 1]
```

You need to use double lines as you need to find the length of the sublist. I don't know or think any direct way exists.